# Display unique values in xslt version 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Can someone help me plz to get a distinct values of attribute ID in node INDIC ?

Explication:

Im using xslt version 1.

- This is how my xml looks like:

  ```
  <Results><Result>
      <INDICS>
          <INDIC ID="I000207" LIB="A"/>
          <INDIC ID="I000208" LIB="B"/>
          <INDIC ID="I999999" LIB="C"/>
      </INDICS>
  </Result>
  <Result>
      <INDICS>
          <INDIC ID="I000207" LIB="A"/>
          <INDIC ID="I000208" LIB="B"/>
          <INDIC ID="I999999" LIB="C"/>
      </INDICS>
  </Result>
  ```

this is how my template looks like, my template display all IDs

```
     <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="INDICS" select="//INDIC"/>
     <PRODUITS>
     <INDICS>
     <xsl:for-each select="//Results/Result/INDICS/INDIC/@ID">
     <INDIC ID= "{.}" LIB="{$INDICS[@ID=current()]/@LIB}" />
     </xsl:for-each>
     </INDICS>
     </PRODUITS>
     </xsl:template>
```

the output that I get is:

```
<PRODUITS>
<INDICS>
<INDIC ID="I000207" LIB="A"/>
<INDIC ID="I000208" LIB="B"/>
<INDIC ID="I999999" LIB="C"/>
<INDIC ID="I000207" LIB="A"/>
<INDIC ID="I000208" LIB="B"/>
<INDIC ID="I999999" LIB="C"/>
 <INDICS/>
</PRODUITS>
```

the output that Im trying to get is:

```
<PRODUITS>
<INDICS>
<INDIC ID="I000207" LIB="A"/>
<INDIC ID="I000208" LIB="B"/>
<INDIC ID="I999999" LIB="C"/>
 <INDICS/>
</PRODUITS>
```

thanks alot.

Comment: There are already many answer like this. Next time please use a [search like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+unique) before asking.

Comment: is like that you help people ? :3

Comment: It's from the usage guidelines for this site. See the second paragraph of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would be grateful if someone can help plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, hope this code help you to solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Results>
            <Result>
                <INDICS>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//INDIC">
                        <xsl:variable name="c-id" select="@ID"/>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$c-id = ancestor::Result/following-sibling::Result/INDICS/INDIC/@ID"/>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <INDIC ID= "{@ID}" LIB="{@LIB}" />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </INDICS>
            </Result>
        </Results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that's exaclty what I was looking for ! thanks Alot ! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility used in the linked questions is using a `xsl:key` and the `generate-id()` function. It is a variation of the so called `Muenchian Grouping`.

```
<xsl:key name="values" match="INDIC" use="@ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <PRODUITS>
        <INDICS>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Results/Result/INDICS/INDIC[generate-id() = generate-id(key('values',@ID)[1])]">
                <INDIC ID= "{@ID}" LIB="{@LIB}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </INDICS>
    </PRODUITS>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sacamoto - It is well worth learning about this techique, as is it is much more efficient with larger data sources. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html